# Google Apps Script: Access the form key that allows user to edit their responses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms

With a Google Apps for Education domain, we can create forms that allows users to edit their response.

This sends a link to the submitter with the url that they can use to edit their response.  Essentially this is the url of the form with a unique key at the end.

At the time of submission, I would like to be able to collect this key and store it with the form data for each user.

We are creating an Alumni website (where all users will be authenticated to our domain), and we'd like to have an update my profile page.  This would be blank the first time the user submits.  But then when they come back, I'd like a script to search the username against submitted entries, and if the user is found, direct them to the link that allows them to update their profile.

At the time of first submission, Google automatically sends the url to the user.  However, t is unlikely that years later, they will stil have this email, so if we could provide the link for them, it would be far easier for the user.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem. One way to solve, is to implement a Gmail plugin(if all users are gmail users). The plugin can parse the message (extractor), and get the key/or the whole URL. But you need to saveit on some database, in order to have acccess later.

If we got some way to list form keys, it should be much better!